# Using bitmap fonts in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, fonts, bitmap, fixed-width

Is it possible to use bitmap (.fon) fonts in Netbeans? I have a font I particularly like ([Raize font](http://www.raize.com/devtools/tools/rzfont.asp)) and I don't see it anywhere on the list when I try to set it as the editor font. 
I can use it in other editors (Notepad++, pspad, visual c++ express etc). I can't use it in jedit either. Is this issue java related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According the [Java API Specification](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) for the [`java.awt.font`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/package-summary.html) package, which is used to add font support to Java, mentions that the following types of fonts are supported:

- Type 1 fonts
- Type 1 Multiple Master fonts
- OpenType fonts
- TrueType fonts

It appears that Microsoft bitmap fonts (`.fon`) are not supported, at least from the information I was able to find.

On a related note, to get a listing of all the `Font`s which are installed in Java at the current time, one can make a call to [`GraphicsEnvironment.getAllFonts`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getAllFonts()) which will return a `Font[]` of all the fonts which can be used.

(Note that the [`GraphicsEnvironment`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html) class cannot be instantiated, but an instance can be obtained by the [`GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()) method.)